# Area which is enclosed by a function of $~r^2=a^2\sin(2\theta)~~(a>0)~$

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates

Find the area enclosed by the following curves.

$$r^2=a^2\sin(2\theta)~~~(a>0)$$

To hold the above identity, we want to determine the range of $~ \theta ~$

$$0\le2\theta\le\pi\iff  \underbrace{0\le\theta\le {\pi \over 2 }}_{\text{This is it} }  $$

$$\begin{align}
A&:= {1 \over 2 } \int_{0}^{\pi\over2}  r(\theta)^2 \mathrm{d}\theta\\
&={1 \over 2 }\int_{0}^{\pi\over2} a^2 \sin(2\theta) \mathrm{d}\theta\\
&={a^2 \over 2 }\int_{0}^{\pi\over2}2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta) \mathrm{d}\theta \\
&={a^2 }\int_{0}^{\pi\over2}\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta) \mathrm{d}\theta\\
I&:=\int \sin(\theta)\cos(\theta) \mathrm{d}\theta\\
t&:=\sin(\theta)\\ {\mathrm{d}t \over \mathrm{d} \theta }&=\cos(\theta)\iff \mathrm{d} t= \mathrm{d} \theta \cos(\theta)\\
I&=\int t \mathrm{d} t \\&= {1 \over 2 }t^2+ \mathrm{const}
 \\&= {1 \over 2 }\sin(\theta)^2+ \mathrm{const}\\
 \therefore A&=a^2 \left\{ {1 \over 2 }\sin(\theta)^2 \right\}\Bigg|_{0}^{\pi\over2} \\
 &={a^2 \over 2 }\sin(\theta)^2\Big|_{0}^{\pi\over2}\\
 &={a^2 \over 2 }
\end{align}$$

But [the book(A First Course in Calculus by Serge Lang)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387962018) says the correct answer is $~ a^2 ~$

Where I've made mistake(s)?

Comment: Why the division by $1/2$ at the beginning?

Comment: @Laplacian That 1/2 is part of polar area formula. https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calcii/PolarArea.aspx

Comment: elec... There is another part of that area in quadrant 3. [$\pi \le \theta \le 3\pi/2$]

Comment: @coffeemath Ah you're right! Well, I guess I am coherent with myself: always forgotten of the $1/2$ and always will :)

Comment: elec... The part in quadrant 3 is the same shape as what you already found so final answer is twice your answer which gives $a^2.$

Comment: @coffeemath I hadn't ever thought about that section(3rd quadrant) X0

Comment: Currently i am in outside so i will write a post of answer later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct equation for the answer is as following.

$$\begin{align}
A&=\color{fuchsia}{\int_{0}^{\pi\over2} {1 \over  2}r(\theta)^2 \mathrm{d} \theta + \int_{\pi}^{3\pi\over2} {1 \over  2}r(\theta)^2 \mathrm{d} \theta}  \\&= {a^2 \over 2  } + {a^2 \over 2 }\sin(\theta)^2\Bigg|_{\pi}^{3\pi\over2} \\&=a^2
\end{align}$$

One should consider for any section of $~0\le\theta\le2\pi$ with this kind of problem.